# Music file not playing

Tags: android, audio-player, android-music-player

Please may you have a look at my code. I can't seem to get it to play music.

```
play.setOnClickListener(new ImageButton.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {

            try{
                AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = Txt.this.getAssets().openFd("hc.mp3");
                player.setDataSource(descriptor.getFileDescriptor(), descriptor.getStartOffset(), descriptor.getLength() );
                descriptor.close();
                player.prepare();
                player.start();
            }
        catch(Exception e){

        }
        }
});
```

Comment: Why bother catching an exception if you're not going to use it to diagnose the issue? Either don't catch the exception and debug in the console, or catch the exception and output the error.

Answer (score 0):

`prepare` is an asynchronous method, you need to [register an OnPreparedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setOnPreparedListener%28android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener%29) before calling `prepare`, and in the listener call to `start`.